# Add Item to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, observablecollection

I have one TextBox which the Text content has data binding to the View Model.
I need to save different string from the TextBox to one collection, but seems it always replicates the last current TextBox's text to all the items. Although each time i have typed different text.

Here is the code in XAML:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 Margin="0,81,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="{Binding Note.NoteTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Height="50" Width="380" 
                 Foreground="#FFB0AEAE" FontSize="26"/>
```

and in the View Model, I have:

```
public Note Note 
{
    get { return _note; }
    set { Set(() => Note, ref _note, value); }
}

private ObservableCollection<Note> _notes;

public async void AddNote(Note note)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AddNote Called...");
    _notes.Add(note);
}
```

There is one button in my page, and when click it, it will call AddNote.

Is there a solution i can save different items into _notes?

Edit:
More information: The reason AddNote to be async is I need to call another task inside to save the note data:

```
private async Task saveNoteDataAsync()
{
  var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Note>));
  using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(fileName,
      CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
  {
    jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, _notes);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". Also see [help/tagging].

Comment: Why you method AddNote is "async" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to push the same instance of Note object again and again. AddNote command should accept only string argument and create a new note before adding.

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 Margin="0,81,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="{Binding NoteTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Height="50" Width="380" 
                 Foreground="#FFB0AEAE" FontSize="26"/>

private string _NoteTitle;
public string NoteTitle
{
    get { return _NoteTitle; }
    set { _NoteTitle= value; }
}

private ObservableCollection<Note> _notes;

public async void AddNote(string NoteName)
{
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AddNote Called...");
        _notes.Add(new Note() {NoteTitle = NoteName});
    });
    // your async calls etc.
}
```

Comment: I thought adding to an ObservableCollection asynchronously would result in an exception? e.g. "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."  Wouldn't that be an issue in this case?

Comment: There may be no need to add additional property - writing *Clone()* method in *Note* and using it `_notes.Add(note.Clone())` should also solve the issue.

Comment: @user2588666 The method posted by OP is still synchronous, async keyword doesn't change anything in this case. Of course on which thread it's being called depends on the resto of the code. Note also that marking method *async* (not needed in this case) is not making the method run on different thread, even the *await* keyword would be there - making your method asynchronous doesn't mean that it will be run on different thread right away.

Comment: If the command or addNote is performed on background thread then yes if not then it should be fine. Use System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { AddNote("") }) in that case

Comment: @Vidas Vasiliauskas, I need to use async becasue, I need to have another task in side of AddNote: await saveNoteDataAsync();

Comment: Then you should mention it in your question, I have adjusted the code for async.

Comment: @VidasVasiliauskas, sorry, I removed that saveNoteDataAsync for debugging purpose.